# Compilation Errors with Gazebo Plugin on Windows

Tags: gazebo, c++, cmake, gazebo-plugin

I am currently working on a project where I need to build a Gazebo plugin for a UR5 model. My development environment is set up on Windows, and I am using MinGW as my compiler within a Conda environment. However, I am facing multiple compilation errors when trying to build my plugin, which includes Gazebo headers.

After successfully running CMake to configure the project, I proceed with the make command. This results in a multitude of errors, many of which seem related to standard C++ libraries and threading. Here are some examples of the errors:

```
C:/w64devkit/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include/c++/optional:1308:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> constexpr bool std::operator<(const optional<_Tp>&, nullopt_t)'
 1308 |     operator<(const optional<_Tp>& /* __lhs */, nullopt_t) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/w64devkit/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include/c++/optional:1308:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/w64devkit/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include/c++/thread:79:32: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::optional<_Tp>'
   79 |     return __x._M_thread < __y._M_thread;
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
C:/w64devkit/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include/c++/optional:1313:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp> constexpr bool std::operator<(nullopt_t, const optional<_Tp>&)'
 1313 |     operator<(nullopt_t, const optional<_Tp>& __rhs) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
C:/w64devkit/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include/c++/optional:1313:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
C:/w64devkit/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/include/c++/thread:79:32: note:   'std::thread::native_handle_type' is not derived from 'const std::optional<_Tp>'
   79 |     return __x._M_thread < __y._M_thread;
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
```

These errors seem to indicate a problem with handling std::thread and possibly other standard library components. I am not sure if these are due to a mismatch between MinGW and the Gazebo libraries, an issue specific to my Conda environment, or something else.
Here is the setup of my CMakeLists.txt for reference:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(UR5Plugin)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# Find the Gazebo package
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)

# Find Eigen3
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)

# Include the Gazebo headers and Eigen headers
include_directories(${GAZEBO_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${GAZEBO_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Create a shared library with your plugin
add_library(ur5_plugin SHARED ur5_plugin.cpp)

# Link the Gazebo libraries and Eigen libraries to your plugin
target_link_libraries(ur5_plugin ${GAZEBO_LIBRARIES} Eigen3::Eigen)
```

`cmake` runs without any issues. On running `make`, all these errors pop up and they only happen when the gazebo headers are included in the `ur5_plugin.cpp` file.

Any help would be appreciated!!!